# How can a closure escape when it's used in a nested function?

Tags: swift, scope, swift3, closures, nested-function

I'm playing around with a recursively defined data structure. Boiling it down to arrays, this is what I do for `map`:

```
func map<T, U>(_ arr: [T], _ mut: T -> U) -> [U] {
    func recMap(_ i : Int) -> [U] {
        if i >= arr.count {
            return []
        } else {
            return [mut(arr[i])] + recMap(i+1)
        }
    }

    if arr.count > 0 {
        return recMap(0)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

This strikes me as a good used of nested functions: the traversal code does not escape the only scope it's needed. (Let's assume that is truly the case here.)

However, Swift complains:

> Declaration closing over non-escaping parameter 'mut' may allow it to escape.

Of course, `recMap` *may* do weird things, but it doesn't; is the issue that the compiler can't figure that out?

What deepens my confusion is that this code works:

```
private func recMap<T, U>(_ arr: [T], _ i : Int, _ mut: (T) -> U) -> [U] {
    if i >= arr.count {
        return []
    } else {
        return [mut(arr[i])] + recMap(arr, i+1, mut)
    }
}

func map<T, U>(_ arr: [T], _ mut: (T) -> U) -> [U] {
    if arr.count > 0 {
        return recMap(arr, 0, mut)
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

Surely, `mut` can escape in the same ways now?

What am I missing? Is there a way to make the first version work?

Comment: Likely just a bug in the compiler. I'd open a bug report. Nested functions aren't always as well supported as they should be.

Comment: @RobNapier Good to know that it's probably not me! Seems to have been [reported](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2274) already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be due to a shortcoming in the component that analyses escaping behaviour; it's apparently a little too defensive.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2274). Current state: Open, Unassigned.